# How can I replace TIMESTAMPDIFF to give me the "final" date and replace

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to make the timediff to show as "final date"

```
START DATE            USETIME     END DATE
--------------------------------------------
2019-04-11 23:01:11     5           -2
```

I want to show in the end date this: 2019-04-11 23:06:11 (it will add the usetime to the start date)

I already tried a few things from MySQL date and time functions but no one worked.

```
MIN(IF(g.usetime > 0, usetime - TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, add_time, now()), 1000000))
```

Using this at this time, the only thing I think i need to change is TIMESTAMPDIFF to something else..

Another problem:
How could I made this work? `REPLACE(REPLACE(usetime,0,'PERM'), add_time + interval usetime minute)` want to replace when is 0 with a word and if not 0 it will make the nice output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
(start_date + interval usertime minute) as end_date
```

Comment: That did the job

Comment: How could I made this work? REPLACE(REPLACE(usetime,0,'PERM'), add_time + interval usetime minute)

Comment: something liek that

Comment: Your question has no mention of `'PERM'`.  Perhaps you should ask a new question.

Comment: added here the question

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
DATE_ADD(START DATE, INTERVAL (select USETIME from tablename) MINUTE);
```